# Configure 3 domains in CloudFlare, with 2 redirecting to the first one, for a wordpress installation in openshift

Tags: redirects, dns, cname, cloudflare

My friend has 3 domains:

- example.com
- example.com.cc
- example.com.co

The website is hosted at OpenShift and it's already redirecting example.com to it (using the guide in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23178367)). So far, so good. We are using CloudFlare in this setup.

**We would like to know how to configure the other domains to redirect to the .com, using only CloudFlare, for a wordpress installation in openshift.**

All nameservers have been changed at the domain registrars, and are set up to be used by CloudFlare to redirect to the .com, but I don't know exactly what I need to do. All the www. subdomains would be redirected to example.com as well.

*There's a similar question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91184/managing-redirections-of-2-domains-at-cloudflare-for-the-same-site) but the solution is to use the hosting control panel, something I don't want to do. My idea here is to use only CloudFlare, since for each domain a different registrar was used, and having all DNS configuration in a single place is better.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although [matts answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/95082/65864) gave me some direction for the "page rule" tip in cloudflare, a bunch of stuff still had to be made.

I'm assuming you already have an application running in openshift: let's suppose it's subdomain is php-example.rhcloud.com, and now you want to add custom domains example.com, example.com.cc and example.com.co to redirect to the application: remember that example.com.cc and example.com.co will redirect to example.com.

1 - Configure domain aliases for example.com, example.com.cc and example.com.co in the [openshift web console](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/domains-ssl.html#_step_1_configure_a_domain_alias_in_the_openshift_web_console_or_command_line_rhc);

2 - Create a Cloudflare account, adding example.com, example.com.cc and example.com.co as your domains;

3 - Go to your domain registrar (I'm using GoDaddy) and change the nameservers to the ones that were given to you when you were adding the domains in cloudflare (in my case it was alec.ns.cloudflare.com and june.ns.cloudflare.com);

4 - "Refresh" your domains in cloudflare, in the "Overview" section to check that cloudflare is now in charge of your DNS;

5 - Time to configure the DNS and Page Rules for your domains:

### example.com

**DNS**

Type: CNAME 
Name: example.com
Value: php-example.rhcloud.com

Type: CNAME 
Name: www
Value: example.com

PS: Remember to check the cloud icon, it needs to be orange.

**Page Rules**

www.example.com/*
Forwarding URL - 301
http://example.com/$1

### example.com.cc

**DNS**

Type: CNAME 
Name: example.com.cc
Value: php-example.rhcloud.com

Type: CNAME 
Name: www
Value: example.com.cc

PS: Remember to check the cloud icon, it needs to be orange.

**Page Rules**

www.example.com.cc/*
Forwarding URL - 301
http://example.com/$1

example.com.cc/*
Forwarding URL - 301
http://example.com/$1

### example.com.co

**DNS**

Type: CNAME 
Name: example.com.co
Value: php-example.rhcloud.com

Type: CNAME 
Name: www
Value: example.com.co

PS: Remember to check the cloud icon, it needs to be orange.

**Page Rules**

www.example.com.co/*
Forwarding URL - 301
http://example.com/$1

example.com.co/*
Forwarding URL - 301
http://example.com/$1

That's it: when you use https, an invalid certificate will issue because you're using a custom domain (example.com) but the certificate is for php-example.rhcloud.com: for you to use custom ssl certificates on the server, you need Bronze or Silver plan from openshift or use Cloudflare certificate.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to redirect mydomain.com.co/url-example to mydomain.com/url-example then some simple page rules in cloudflare for the 2 other domains to do a 301 redirect back to the main domain would do the trick.

If you need to redirect with url, the ideal case would be to set up server with 3 virtual hosts with the domains. When user visits a domain to be redirect the .htaccess file redirects them with 301 to the correct domain.

For mydomain.com.cc use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com.cc$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://www\.mydomain\.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So I need to create page rules? Can't I do it just using CNAMEs?

Comment: Since the OP wants to use only CloudFlare, _Page Rules_ would be the way to go here. You actually can redirect URLs using variables and wildcards. See the bottom of this support doc from CloudFlare for examples:  [How do I perform URL forwarding or redirects with CloudFlare?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-CloudFlare-)

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS You'd need to use Page Rules. Using a `CNAME` would point one host to another, but not handle URL rewrites, which would need to be done via the web server otherwise (like matt pointed out above).

Comment: @dan I don't know if my friend needs url rewrites, these domains were mainly to avoid copyright issues. I tried a CNAME pointing example.com.cc to example.com but it didn't work, I get "too many redirects" (`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`) error.

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS Did you see my comments above? You should use _Page Rules_ not a CNAME. You're likely seeing that because the server has redirects and hence you're stuck in a redirect loop. Remove those, and just use Page Rules.

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS as dan said above , don't use CNAME,  Simple page rules in cloudflare would handle exactly what you want to do. 1 rule for each of the 2 domains to be redirected.

Comment: If I remove the CNAMES and just add Page Rules, I get `This site can’t be reached server DNS address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` when trying to access example.com.cc, and the following messages on cloudflare admin: `An A, AAAA or CNAME record was not found for the www subdomain. The www.example.com.cc subdomain will not resolve.
An A, AAAA or CNAME record was not found pointing to the root domain. The example.com.cc domain will not resolve.`.

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS Prior to using Page Rules, you need to make sure the DNS for `www.example.com.cc` is setup correctly in CloudFlare with an `A` record pointing towards the root domain and a CNAME pointing to the `A` record. CloudFlare also has to be active on those (the orange cloud instead of grey). Then you can use Page Rules. I'd suggest reviewing [DNS](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/categories/200276237) and how to use CloudFlare a bit more.